# Is there a specific function that I can use in order to assign a different name every time I run the code?

Tags: r

I was asked to create a function that prints my student id and then exports a data frame to a CSV. file, which name is supplied to the function as an argument. This is the code that I managed to write, but it gives some type of error and I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

```r
MyFunction <- function(DataName){
  print("theID")
  proba123=save(MyFunction, ".csv")
  filename=paste0(proba123,".CSV")
  write.csv(data_list, proba123)
}
```

The error states " Error in save(MyFunction, ".csv") : object ‘.csv’ not found" and I know that my mistake is there, but I am not really sure how to fix it. Basically, my professor told me that I can write the name of the action as an argument in the function that saves the file and, therefore, I tried, but I failed miserably.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the error that you actually get?  Your second line of code looks weird; can you explain what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do in that line `proba123 = ...` ? You should probably use the argument (`DataName`) somewhere.  Can you get more help from your professor, or from someone else in your group?